# How to make Format ABC-1234 in regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I have done formatting using regular expressions:

```
<p class="phone">2124771000</p>
 $(".phone").text(function(i, text) {
        text = text.replace(/(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d\d)/, "$1-$2-$3");
        return text;
    });
```

Using this above example I am able to convert 212-477-1000:

```
<p class="phone">ABC1234</p>
```

Now I want to Make **ABC-1234** string using above text .

Testing environment : http://jsfiddle.net/Xxk3F/4237/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your wanting to capture both in 1 regex..

You can use an either expression `|`

eg.

`/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})|([A-Z]{3})(\d{4})$/`

```js
function replacer(m, p1,p2,p3, p4,p5) {
  if (p1) return [p1,p2,p3].join('-')
  else return [p4,p5].join('-');
}

$(".phone").text(function(i, text) {
  text = text.replace(/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})|([A-Z]{3})(\d{4})$/, replacer);
  return text;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="phone">ABC1234</p>
<p class="phone">1231231234</p>
<p class="phone">XYZ2345</p>
<p class="phone">9999999999</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

The following will check for 3 uppercase letters followed by 4 numbers:

```
$(".phone").text(function(i, text) {
    text = text.replace(/([A-Z]{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2");
    return text;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this for `ABC1234`:

```js
$(".phone").text(function(i, text) {
  text = text.replace(/([a-z]+(?=\d+))/i, "$1-");
  return text;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="phone">ABC1234</p>
```

And for phone numbers, try this:

```js
$(".phone").text(function(i, text) {
  text = text.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3");
  return text;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="phone">2124771000</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this pattern

```
text = text.replace(/([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)/, "$1-$2");
```